# How to get the status of all requests to one API in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, express

I want to get API server status in nodejs. I'm using nodejs to open an interface: "api/request?connId=50&timeout=90". This API will keep the request running for provided time on the server side. After the successful completion of the provided time it should return status/OK. And when we have multiple connection ids & timeout, we want the API return all the running requests on the server with their time left for completion, something like below, where 4 and 8 are the `connId` and 25 and 15 is the time remaining for the requests to complete (in seconds):

```
{"4":"25","8":"15"}
```

please help.

Comment: I am little bit confused with your need. When you send a request on endpoint like `api/request?connId=50&timeout=90`, will the server take takeout time provided by the request?? And you also supply the connId yourself?? And after that you will also want to get the information of request like you stated in another endpoint??

Comment: In order to know all `connId`'s startTime and Timeout value, you need to store them in one place: a global variable, memory database such as Redis, or plain database such as MongoDB etc. What have your tried so far?

Comment: hii Tolsee,i have passed connectionId and timeout .after then when we try 'api/serverStatus' ,than i want information regarding to all connection IDs,as well as discussed in my question.then i am confused how does calculate the remaining time corresponding to all connId....thanks

Comment: @shaochuancs ,actuall i want all the running requests on the server with their time left for completion.not the who has completed already.so i am little confused how to track all running requests with given connectionIDS.if i will use any database than i have fount only stored connectionsIDS record not running process.

Comment: For `time left for completion`, is it only decided by startTime and Timeout value? Or is it request mission specific?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js server uses async model in one single thread, which means at any time, only one request (`connId`) is under execution by Node (except... you have multiple node.js instance, but let's keep the scenario simple and ignore this case).

When one request is processed (running its handler code), it may start an async task such as read a file, and continue execution. The request itself's handler code would be executed without waiting for async task, and when this handler code is finished running, from Node.js point of view, the request handling itself is done -- the handling of async task's result is another thing in another time, node does not care about the progress of it.

Thus, in order to return remaining time of all requests -- I guess this is the remaining time of other request's async task, because remaining time of other request's handler code execution does not make any sense, there must be some place to store the information of all requests, including:

- request's `connId` and startTime (the time when request is received).
- request's `timeout` value, which is passed as parameter in URL.
- request's estimated remaining time, this information is mission specific and must be retrieved from other async task related services (you can pull time by time using `setInterval` or make other services push the latest remaining time). Node.js doesn't know the remaining time information of any async task.

In this way, you can track all running requests and their remaining time. Before one request is returned, you can check the above "some place" to calculate all requests' remaining time. This "some place" could be global variable, memory database such as Redis, or even a plain database such as MySQL.

Please note: the calculated remaining time would not be accurate, as the read&calculation itself would cost time and introduce error.